# Can an employee pay for boss' things?

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-law, corporate-tax-laws

If someone had a trusted remote employee living in Saudi Arabia where there's no taxes, would it be possible for them to instead of paying themselves a wage, pay the foreign employee extra and then the foreign employee buys the employer whatever he needs? I.e they can buy them a car, pay their energy bills etc?

This way they could be able to pay zero taxes in total?

Answer (score 1):

### Can this happen?

Sure.

### Is it legal?

Oh my, no.

It’s clearly an illegal [tax avoidance scheme](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/tax-avoidance-an-introduction).